# Custom Message Box displays after Message box

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, messagebox

I have some code that when I call my `CustomMessageBox` it displays the box with a user prompt for an amount of my object to add, once that is done I have it added to a list of objects. Once added, it then Displays a `MessageBox.Show` to just let the user know it was added.

My problem is that when I run the code it executes all the code, bypasses the display of the Custom message box, then displays the `MessageBox.Show`, and THEN displays the CMB.Show. I ran the code through the debugger and followed the trail and it hits the CMB.Show before the MessageBox.Show, but is displayed once the code is done. Sorry, I am still learning and might not be telling the problem well, please let me know if there is anything I can further explain upon.

Some code:

```
    private int BasicLand(Card basicLand)
    {
        var countBox = new TextBox
        {
            Name = "count",
            Width = 100,
        };


        var cmbCount = new CustomMessageBox
        {
            Caption = "Blah",
            Content = countBox,
            RightButtonContent = "ok",
        };

        cmbCount.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>
        {
            switch (e1.Result)
            {
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
                    if (int.TryParse(countBox.Text, out tempInt) && Convert.ToInt32(countBox.Text) > 0)
                    {
                        countReturn = Convert.ToInt32(tempInt);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Some code for error....
                    }
            }
        };

        cmbCount.Show();

    return countReturn;
    }
```

Then the other part that triggers first but is last in the code block.

```
    MessageBox.Show("Object was added to List!");
```

I tried adding the ShowDialog to the custom box but it came up broken in VS. BasicLand is called within another method and when the object is added to the list it will display the MessageBox.Show.

Comment: It'll be hard to guess what's going on without seeing the actual code

Comment: need to show code.. also sounds like a ShowModal problem..meaning change MessageBox.Show to MessageBox.ShowModal() for the CustomMessageBox but I am only guessing not seeing the actual code..

Comment: Updated with code, thank you for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Martin: I am using Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, it does not take into account that any user interaction is asynchronous. When you call `Show()` it will actually show the messagebox, but it will not block your currently running thread, the other statements after the call to `Show()` will be executed immediately and thus your method returns a returnvalue that has not been provided by the user but is just the default. To fix this you have to write your code in continuations.

```
private void PromtUserForFeeblefezerAmount(Action<int> continueFeeblefzing, Action cancel)
{
    var messagebox = CreateFeeblefezerPromt();
    messagebox.Dismissed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if ( args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton )
            continueFeeblefzing( GetFeeblefezerAmount(messagebox) );
        else
            cancel();
    };
    messagebox.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. I appreciate your help and patience.